# How to show data from different table in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Terms table

- term_id
- name
- slug

Term_taxonomy table

- term_taxonomy_id
- term_id
- description

i want to show all record like "term_id , name , description

my Term model

```
public function TermTaxonomy(){
    return $this->hasOne('TermTaxonomy');
}
```

my TermTaxonomy model

```
public function Term(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Term');
}
```

my route

```
$term = new Term;
$categories = $term->all(['term_id', 'name']);
foreach($categories as $category){
    echo $category->term_id . " " . $category->name . " " . "description of term_id should here" ;}
```

trying this code but Error Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$TermTaxonomy

```
$e = new Term;
$f = $e->all(['term_id','name']);
    echo $f->TermTaxonomy->description;
}
```

with the above code i want to return all description of each term_id, but i am confusing why i can show description if the object just 1 , like this code below

```
$a = new Term;
$b = $a->all(['term_id','name'])->find(8);
echo $b->TermTaxonomy->description . "<br>"; // work return description of $b;
```

so what is exactly one to one relationship function ? is one to one only work when the object just 1 ?

what about in my case ? is my logic wrong to show all description using relationship method ? then what must i do to show term id , name , description lists ?

thanks in advance, i am totally newbie in laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access relationships on collections directly. I mean, what would you even expect? All descriptions as comma separated list?

Instead you just access the relation when you loop over all of them anyways. (That's probably in the view so I'm going to use Blade syntax in this example)

```
@foreach($terms as $term)
    {{ $term->term_id }} {{ $term->name }} {{ ($term->TermTaxonomy ? $term->TermTaxonomy->description : '') }}
@endforeach
```

`($term->TermTaxonomy ? $term->TermTaxonomy->description : '')` is a [shorthand if](http://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples). It means:

```
if($term->TermTaxonomy){
    echo $term->TermTaxonomy->description;
}
else {
    echo '';
}
```

It works because if the `Term` has no `TermTaxonomy` assigned, `$term->TermTaxonomy` will be null. With this code we only try to access `->description` if `TermTaxonomy` exists and can therefore avoid a `Trying to get property of non-object` exception.

---

**Attention:** While this works you definitely should *eager load* the `TermTaxonomy` relationship. You see if we leave it like that, each time you do `$term->TermTaxonomy` a DB query will be run. To avoid n+1 queries, use `with` to eager load relationships:

```
$terms = Term::with('TermTaxonomy')->get(['term_id','name']);
```

---

Regarding your question in the comments, yes you can limit the fields that you select from `term_taxonomy`:

```
$terms = Term::with(['TermTaxonomy' => function($q){
    $q->select('term_id', 'description');
}])->get(['term_id','name']);
```

Just make sure you include the columns necessary to make the relationship (in this case `term_id`)

Comment: hello @lukasgeiter just trying this 

`$terms = Term::with('TermTaxonomy')->get(['term_id','name']); foreach($terms as $term){ echo $term->term_id . " " . $term->name . " " . $term->TermTaxonomy->description; }`

and i get **Trying to get property of non-object** but if i remove `$ term->TermTaxonomy->description` , the code is working but only show term_id and name.

Comment: Maybe you have some terms that have no `TermTaxonomy` assigned in the db? I updated the code in my answer with an if that checks for that...

Comment: yes you are right some terms not assigned in the db, but don't know why now its work without delete not assigned term or term taxonomy. but if i try print() , it will return term_id , name fields from terms table and all fields from term taxonomy table , how i can spesific few fields only from term taxonomy table with get() function ? then tell me more the function of `($term->TermTaxonomy ? $term->TermTaxonomy->description : '')` and maybe you can give me link about it. thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your awesome answer, this exactly what i want. proud to be your friend. hehe :D

Comment: anyway, just trying again my code and get **Trying to get property of non-object** then checking my db and delete terms table record which not assigned to term_taxonomy table or simply don't have partner in term_taxonomy table , and my code is working. so your previous comment about assigned in the db is totally correct. but your shorthand if seems not working for me to avoid trying to get propert of non object. but its no important problem, maybe you want fix shorthand if hehe.

Comment: and a little correction for your shorthand if, with this code `echo $term->term_id ." ". $term->name ." ". $term->TermTaxonomy ? $term->TermTaxonomy->description ."<br>" : '' ;`  it only show description field, so i change to `echo $term->TermTaxonomy ? $term->term_id ." ". $term->name ." ". $term->TermTaxonomy->description ."<br>" : '' ;` then i get what i want :D.

Comment: Does this work? `echo $term->term_id . " " . $term->name . " " . ($term->TermTaxonomy ? $term->TermTaxonomy->description . "<br>" : "");`

Comment: just trying my previous code `echo $term->TermTaxonomy ? $term->term_id ." ". $term->name ." ". $term->TermTaxonomy->description ."<br>" : '' ;` and nevermind if my code already avoid **trying to get blabla** BUT it will show all record **which already assigned each other** between terms and term taxonomy table so record which don't have partner will not appear. then with your new code it avoid **Trying to get blabla** and it will show all terms record **even** some record dont have partner with term taxonomy so i just need to use what i need. thanks for awesome answer @lukasgeiter

Answer (score 0):

If you do a `$e-all`, you get an array with the `TermTaxanomies`. When you do a specific search (`->find(8)`) you only get that object with id = 8.

All you need to do is use a foreach or use an index number:

```
$f = $e->all(['term_id','name']);
foreach($f as $tax){
    var_dump($tax);
}
```

Or

```
$f = $e->all(['term_id','name']);
var_dump($f[1]);
var_dump($f[4]);
```

I think that should work.

Comment: thanks for your answer bro, but how i can show description of each term ? actually i want to show term_id , name , description. so far i can show term_id , name but dont know how to show description. thanks

Comment: $f = $e->all(); gives you records with all the fields. you can access them in the foreach with $tax->field_name

Comment: `$f = $e->all();` only show record from terms table only since `$e` is point to Term model. and i need to show description field from Term_taxonomy table. and the problem is i can't call TermTaxonomy method by the relationship from Term Model. :D

Comment: You can! Use `$e->TermTaxanomy->description` Notice that the name `TermTaxanomy` is exactly the name as your relation function (without the '()').

Comment: Just trying this code 

`$e = new Term;
$f = $e->all();
var_dump($e->TermTaxonomy->description);`

and the result is 
**Trying to get property of non-object **

Then if i try below code 

`$e = new Term;
$f = $e->all();
var_dump($f->TermTaxonomy->description);`

the result is **Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$TermTaxonomy**

Answer (score 0):

oops! Looks like you're trying to implement raw php code into Laravel. Please get rid of that , follow the instructions bellow.

make a `Route`:

```
    Route::get('/term' , array('uses' => 'TermsController@showTerm'));
```

Now make a Controller named `TermsController.php` and try something like bellow:

```
       <?php
          class TermsController extends BaseController {
               public function showTerm(){
                       $terms = Term::all();
              return View::make('show_term.blade.php')->with('terms' , $terms);
           }
       }//class ends
```

Now make a Model named `Term.php` :

```
 <?php
       class Terms extends \Eloquent{
         protected $fillable = array();
         protected $table = 'terms'; //terms is your database table name
   }?>
```

Now make a `show_term.blade.php` :

```
   @extends(layouts.master)
   @section('content)
    foreach($terms as term){
     {{$term->id}} , {{$term->name}} , {{$term->slug}}}
      @stop
```

if you don't have the `layouts.master` then create a `layouts` folder inside you View folder. Then create a `master.blade.php` write the basic html and inside the body try like this:

```
  <div class="container"> 
    @yield('content')
   </div>
```

Thank you . Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: then, how to show description of each term bro ? is my above code right to show description using one to one relationships , or how i can show description ? thanks in advance. :D

Comment: I think you're not clear about your question , or may be I am. However , I showed an illustrative example to you . If you want to show your description , then simply go throw the above example. to get the description , first pass a variable which calls the model related to the desired table (where the description is). Then call the description with a foreach loos as shown. Thank you .

Comment: yes i can get description if i calls the model related to term_taxonomy table, but in this case , is it possible to get description from Term model, since term model have one to one relationship to TermTaxonomy model ?. anyway your given answer teach me how to code laravel in best order i think.

Comment: Okay , That's not possible to grab the description from Term. Now if you think my answer helped you , then you can up-vote and accept the answer. Thank you . :)